# WebLogic 12.1.3, javax.websocket implementation, how to disable idle timeout?

Tags: java, websocket, weblogic

I was using the javax.websocket [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG1025) for websockets within my weblogic application server
I encountered the following message when idle for 5 seconds or more:

```
<Closing the socke
t, as no data read from it on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49,895 during the configured idle
timeout of 5 seconds.>
```

is there a way for me to disable the timeout from my java implementation(not to increase it but to disable it entirely)?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A value that is 0 or negative indicates the sessions will never timeout due to inactivity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html#setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout-long-